# Short story: Sleep pods compress the time you need to sleep, people go crazy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story way back in 2006/2007 when I was in fifth grade that I cannot remember the name of. In the story there are pods resembling telephone booths you can enter to experience a full nights sleep in a short span of time. After a while however, the people using the pods go crazy and die. I can't remember much else about it, however.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is an interesting question, but we don't know how old you are, so we don't know when you were in 5th grade.  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for a good story-identification question and see if there are any other details you can add to your question.

Comment: There's a [Doctor Who episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_No_More_(Doctor_Who)) with a plot like that.